# Having issues deploying an .exe with a SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-ce

On my PC, I can read from the `.SDF` SQL Server CE database file just fine no matter where I place it, but it won't even log on if I send it to someone else to test.

Any ideas?

The current files:

- Pizza Hut.application
- Pizza Hut.exe
- Pizza Hut.exe.config
- Pizza Hut.exe.manifest
- Pizza Hut.pdb
- PIZZAHUT.sdf

And this is the `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MAKESUSHIEntities" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Datos.ModMakeSushi.csdl|res://*/Datos.ModMakeSushi.ssdl|res://*/Datos.ModMakeSushi.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PIZZAHUT.sdf&quot;"
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="Sistema_Restaurante.Properties.Settings.MAKESUSHIConnectionString"
             connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PIZZAHUT.sdf;Initial Catalog=MAKESUSHI;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE: It does not works on my computer if I uninstall SQL Server CE 3.5. I placed the `.dll`s in the folder where the `.exe` and `.SDF` files are and it does not works. What are my options?

Comment: Feel free to share a repro project with me privately, and I will have a look.

Comment: @ErikEJ sent you the projects through your hotmail.